# Should I continue using R v2.8.1?

Tags: r, version

I've been using R v2.8.1 for a long time. Normally I would upgrade it to the latest version but something keeps me away from the builds later than 2.8.1:

I use

`read.table(file=file.choose(),header=TRUE)`

frequently in my libraries. After upgrading to 2.9.0, R started not to remember the latest directory used while selecting file. I downgraded to 2.8.1 and now R can remember again the last directory used. I don't know why they changed that behavior in this direction but this is absolutely crucial for me. It wastes my time in v2.9.0 every time I try to find a specific directory when R cannot remember it.

Now R 2.10.1 is released. I don't know if they have corrected this issue. Should I upgrade or is it just enough to continue using v2.8.1? Will I miss something if I stick at 2.8.1?

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question: Why not ask the people behind R?

Comment: Because I thought there are experienced R users in SO community and they can provide me with the answer.

Comment: 2.10 was released about four months ago. If you do decide to upgrade, you might want to wait an other couple of weeks for the production release of version 2.11, due April 22.

Comment: I just do fresh installation of R-2.10.1 and it remember directory.

Comment: @Marek: Please write your comment as an answer. I will try 2.10.1 and accept your answer if it solves my problem.

Comment: It is more complicated than I thought. On other PC it not working (same installation). It may be OS depended. I will investigate it.

Answer (score 3):

You could take care of the latest directory used yourself. For instance, you could edit your .Rprofile and add a function .Last that stores the latest directory in a file and a function .First that reads that file und sets the working directory. Something similar to

```
.Last <- function() cat(getwd(), file="~/.Rlastdir")
.First <- function() setwd(readLines("~/.Rlastdir"))
```

Comment: This will change working directory. I don't think that is acceptable solution in case you just want to `file.choose` remember directory.